# Оформление кнопки input type=file

Tags: html, css

```
<input type="file" name="xmlfile" id="file" class="button_silver_130" />
```

Вызывает два элемента, один показывает путь до файла, второй элемент это кнопка для вызова окна выбора файла, и тут возникает вопрос, как для двух этих элементов сделать разные css оформления? Например для кнопки "обзор" сделать background-image?

Answer (score 4):

Держите реализацию идеи от **kemerov4anin**

```js
function getName (str){
    if (str.lastIndexOf('\\')){
        var i = str.lastIndexOf('\\')+1;
    }
    else{
        var i = str.lastIndexOf('/')+1;
    }      
    var filename = str.slice(i);   
    var uploaded = document.getElementById("fileformlabel");
    uploaded.innerHTML = filename;
}
```

```css
.fileform { 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 26px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 230px;
}
.fileform .selectbutton { 
    background-color: #A2A3A3;
    border: 1px solid #939494;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50px;
}
.fileform #upload{
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width:100%; 
    -moz-opacity: 0; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
    opacity: 0; 
    font-size: 150px; 
    height: 30px; 
    z-index:20;
}
.fileform #fileformlabel { 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fileform">
  <div id="fileformlabel"></div>
  <div class="selectbutton">Обзор</div>
  <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" onchange="getName(this.value);" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ну label же можно...

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен, можно и label.

Answer (score 2):

А никак. Тут только 1 вариант-прятать input под div и уже сам div оформлять.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?